# Saving an EMF Model

Tags: java, emf

I m new to EMF and trying to save an EMF Model as Follows:-

```
public void saveData(File file, Device device) throws IOException {  

        final ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

        // Use XMI resource
        System.out.println("file path in  saveData " +file.getPath());          
        Resource xmiResource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createFileURI(file.getPath() + ".xmi"));
        xmiResource.getContents().add(device);
        xmiResource.save(null);

        // Use XML resource instead
        Resource xmlResource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createFileURI(file.getPath() + ".xml"));
        xmlResource.getContents().add(device);
        xmlResource.save(null);

        }
```

But no file is created in the designated Path. Code for Loading is:-

```
public Device loadData(String fileName) {


        final ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();


            // Use XMI resource

            Resource xmiResource;
            System.out.println("filename" + fileName);
            try {
            xmiResource = resourceSet.getResource(URI.createFileURI(fileName + ".xmi"),true);

                xmiResource.load(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return (Device)xmiResource.getContents().get(0);

        }
```

which gives the following Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a resource for 'file:/C:/Users/Desktop/filename.xmi'; a registered resource factory is needed

Comment: This sounds like your problem: [Eclipse Forum: "a registered resource factory is needed" outside the generated editor](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/123514/377407/#msg_377407). You could try it and write your own answer to your question if it works to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Used XMiResourceImpl.It is Working fine for Now.

```
XMIResourceImpl resource = new XMIResourceImpl();
 File source = new File(fileName);
 resource.load( new FileInputStream(source), new HashMap<Object,Object>());
 Data data = (Data)resource.getContents().get(0);
```

for saving the model

```
Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
Map<String, Object> m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
m.put("key", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
Resource resource = resSet.createResource(URI.createFileURI(fileName));
resource.getContents().add(data);
resource.save(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```